# Is there any way to create circural reference with Nim?

Tags: circular-reference, nim-lang

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
type
  User = ref object
    email: string
    session: Session # ERROR! undeclared identifier 'Session'

type 
  Session = ref object 
    key: string
    user: User
```

Is there any way to do it with Nim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the answer is to do it with single "type" statment like this:

```
type
  User = ref object
    email: string
    session: Session # NO ERROR :)
  Session = ref object 
    key: string
    user: User
```